# Tensor Invariants

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I was learning about tensors and vectors and it was mentioned in class that they were "invariant" objects that take on specific representations in different bases. I get this for vectors -- I can compute the magnitude of a vector and it shouldn't change under basis change. And for a 2 index tensor, the trace or determinant are invariant.

But what about tensors with more indices -- is there something that remains invariant under isometrics?

And are the invariants for mixed tensors (e.g. rank(1,1) -- linear transformation) the same as totally co/contravariant tensors (e.g. rank(0,2) -- metric tensor) of same form (e.g. determinants and traces)?

thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in quantities that are invariant under all changes of basis, or only those that are invariant under isometries?

Comment: I didn't think about that distinction. In both situations.